# How to sort in Dired by size and extension and have directories listed first and full date/time details

Tags: dired, sorting

I'm using the excelent `dired-fixups.el` by Dino Chiesa for sorting in Dired by size and extension (see [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredSortBySizeAndExtension)).

The only gotcha is that I'd like to combine it with a fuller date/time description. Also, I'd like to keep directories on top of any Dired buffer, so they don't mix with files. That is, I'd like to combine `dired-fixups.el` with something like this:

```
(setq ls-lisp-format-time-list  '("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S" "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
      ls-lisp-use-localized-time-format t)

(defun ls-lisp-format-time (file-attr time-index now)
    "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S" "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")

  (if (eq system-type 'gnu/linux)
      (setq dired-listing-switches "-alDh --group-directories-first --time-style \"+%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S\""))

  (defun ensure-buffer-name-ends-in-slash ()
    "change buffer name to end with slash"
    (let ((name (buffer-name)))
      (if (not (string-match "/$" name))
          (rename-buffer (concat name "/") t))))

  (add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'ensure-buffer-name-ends-in-slash)

  (add-hook 'dired-mode-hook
            (lambda()
              (setq truncate-lines 1)))
```

However, I'm not a programmer. I've been tweaking with the code in `dired-fixups.el` to no avail. Probably it is not too difficult... Does anybody know how to get an outcome like the following snapshot, but where I can use all the sorting options in `dired-fixups.el`?

```
  /home/dgm/.emacs.d/src:
  total used in directory 364K available 15413252
  drwxr-xr-x 21 dgm dgm  12K 29-03-2020 23:27:42 ..
  drwxr-xr-x 14 dgm dgm 4.0K 29-03-2020 09:05:19 .
  drwxr-xr-x  2 dgm dgm 4.0K 05-09-2019 23:58:20 org-recipes
  drwxr-xr-x  2 dgm dgm 4.0K 09-08-2019 12:52:48 ambrevar
  drwxr-xr-x  8 dgm dgm 4.0K 21-04-2019 16:10:22 ado-mode-1.15.1.4
  drwxr-xr-x  2 dgm dgm 4.0K 07-12-2018 15:57:55 ob-stata
  drwxr-xr-x  7 dgm dgm 4.0K 06-12-2018 11:26:01 dvc
  drwxr-xr-x  2 dgm dgm 4.0K 06-12-2018 11:26:01 minimal
  drwxr-xr-x  2 dgm dgm 4.0K 06-12-2018 11:26:01 org-bullets
  drwxr-xr-x  2 dgm dgm 4.0K 06-12-2018 11:26:01 smooth-scrolling
  drwxr-xr-x  2 dgm dgm 4.0K 06-12-2018 11:26:01 stripe-buffer
  drwxr-xr-x  2 dgm dgm 4.0K 06-12-2018 11:26:01 wc
  drwxr-xr-x  2 dgm dgm 4.0K 06-12-2018 11:26:01 word-count
  drwxr-xr-x  2 dgm dgm 4.0K 06-12-2018 11:26:01 bookmarkplus
  -rw-r--r--  1 dgm dgm 4.9K 29-03-2020 09:05:19 dired-fixups.el
  -rw-r--r--  1 dgm dgm  36K 28-03-2020 22:12:11 dired-sort-menu.el
  -rw-r--r--  1 dgm dgm  17K 28-03-2020 22:10:05 dired-sort-menu+.el
  -rw-r--r--  1 dgm dgm 4.6K 27-01-2020 19:47:40 org-graph-view.el
  -rw-r--r--  1 dgm dgm  38K 27-01-2020 19:47:23 graph.el
  -rw-r--r--  1 dgm dgm 6.0K 02-01-2020 16:08:56 window-highlight.el
```

Answer (score 1):

Library [Dired Sort Menu](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredSortMenu) ([`dired-sort-menu.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired-sort-menu.el)) lets you do what you ask.

From the menu, choose **Dirs First**, and choose any of these menu items at the same time (**Dirs First** is a toggle option):

- **Name**
- **Time Modified**
- **Size**
- **Extension**
- **Unsorted**
- **Time Created**

See the screenshot at [Dired Sort Menu](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredSortMenu).

(If you don't want to use a *menu* you can use its code to create commands you can bind to keyboard keys.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I'm aware of this other .el file... Somehow though I prefer Dino's .el. Can't remember exactly why now. Anyway, I'd like to know how can I tinker with Dino's file so that I can get what he gets but with the added benefit of a full date/time stamp on all entries and with directories listed first.

Comment: For the record: I now think it is not worthwhile spending time customizing Dired in the way I meant earlier. Dired already caters for all sorting needs. `C-u s` prompts for switches to sort the contents of the Dired buffer by: `-t` for time, newest 1st; `-S` for file size, largest 1st; `-X` for extension; `-r` for reversing; `-U` for directory order. Long live Emacs and its manual!